# Class implementing interface containing same interface

Tags: java, class, interface

I can't think of a reason why I shouldn't do this but I wanted to see if I was missing something. 
If I have a class that implements an interface is there any reason not to have member objects of a different class implementing the same interface?

```
public class MemberClass implements MyInterface{
}

public class LargerClass implements MyInterface{
    private MemberClass memberClass = new MemberClass;
}
```

Would there be any problems that would apply to most interfaces that would not apply to marker interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's absolutely fine, and is often used for delegation, e.g. in the decorator pattern. While it's not actually using *interfaces* (instead using an abstract base class, `Stream`), [`BufferedStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an example of this.

Or for example you could create a "concatenating iterable":

```
public class Concatenation<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> first;
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> second;

    public Concatenation(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Implicitly calls first.GetEnumerator()
        foreach (T item in first)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        // Implicitly calls second.GetEnumerator()
        foreach (T item in second)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

(`Enumerable.Concat` in LINQ effectively does this...)

Answer (score 4):

I see no problem, just two classes that happen to implement the same interface.

I'd love to hear the design justification that made such a thing necessary, but I don't believe the compiler or runtime will complain.

Comment: I'm considering an Animatable object that contains Animation objects both implementing the interface VisibleObject. VisObj having abstract methods used for anything that should be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid and is in fact a classic example of the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), where here your `LargerClass` is decorating `MemberClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the example of the Decorator Pattern.

In this pattern you have a class implementing an interface which is exactly the same than the one implemented by contained object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem. Moreover there is a well-known design pattern named Wrapper (or Decorator) that is defined as following:

```
public interface Business {
    public void doSomething();
}


public class BusinessWrapper implements Business {
    private Business wrapped;

    public void doSomething() {
        // probably do something before
        wrapped.doSomething();
        // probably do something after
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Programatically/ syntactically yes, You can do it. But from a "Design " prespective, is it right?.

Suppose you have an Animal interface and your Dog class implements it. Now, if you have 2 classes Dog and Cat implementing the same interface, you can't have a Dog/Cat inside the other class. There might be some cases in which this would work (as other's suggest, the decorator pattern..)